# Some doubts related to statistic entropy concept in ID3 machine learning algorithm

Tags: algorithm, statistics, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, entropy

I am studying the **statistic entropy concept used by ID3 machine learning algorithm**

For a domain exemplified by the learning set S (that is the set of the examples that I use to build a decision tree), the average amount of information I needed to classify an object is given by the **entropy measiure**

So I have the following formula:

[image]

So, for example:

**If S is a collection of 14 examples with 9 YES and 5 NO examples then I have that:**

**Entropy(S) = - (9/14)*Log2(9/14) - (5/14)*Log2(5/14) = 0.940**

This is pretty simple to calculate, my problem is that, on my book I also read this note:

> Notice entropy is 0 if all members of S belong to the same class (the
>   data is perfectly classified). The range of entropy is 0 ("perfectly
>   classified") to 1 ("totally random").

This assertion is confusing me because I am trying to change the previous example in this way:

**If S is a collection of 14 examples with 14 YES and 0 NO examples then I have that:**

**Entropy(S) = - (14/14)*Log2(14/14) - (0/14)*Log2(0/14) = 0 - infinity**

So, in this case, I have that all the objecs belong to the same class (YES) and no examples belong to the NO class.

So I would expect that the entropy value of this S set will be 0 and no **- infinity**

What am I missing?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: Typical solution: In the case of p(xi) = 0 for some i, the value of the corresponding summand 0 logb(0) is taken to be 0, which is consistent with the well-known limit. (from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory))

Comment: [http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+x+-%3E+0+x*log2%28x%29+](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+x+-%3E+0+x*log2%28x%29+)

Comment: @fordprefect Oh yes !!! I studied mathematical analysis several years ago and I have don't think to the well known limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calculating entropy you do a summation by iterating over the unique classification values at the node in question. You do this on each iteration by counting how many members of the set have the value, and then use the log formula. In your problem case, the only classification value that occurs is YES, meaning that entropy is zero based on the single iteration. You cannot iterate on a NO value because none of the examples have that value.